# How do I unlock Rosalina in Mario Kart Wii?

Tags: mario-kart-wii

How do I unlock Rosalina from Super Mario Galaxy as a playable racer in Mario Kart Wii?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [this guide](http://www.videogamesblogger.com/2008/04/18/how-to-unlock-all-mario-kart-wii-secret-characters-bikes-karts-and-more-guide.htm) ,

> Rosalina: Get a “One Star” rank or better in all Mirror Mode Wii-Cups. Or if you have a saved game file from Super Mario Galaxy, you should win 50 Grand Prix races.

You can also get Rosalina by finishing a total of 4,960 races.

Comment: Are you sure? She's always been unlocked for me. I do have a SMG savegame.

Comment: I do have SMG save but Rosalina never shows up.

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways: have a Super Mario Galaxy save file and she will be unlocked after 50 races or get 1 star in all 8 Mirror Mode Cups.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, according to this site: http://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Kart_Wii

> Rosalina
>
> Have a Super Mario Galaxy save file and play 50 races, attain at least 1 Star Rank for all 150cc Mirror Grand Prix cups, or play 4,950 races

Comment: I am pretty sure it is 4K, not 4.95K.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of unlocking rosalina. . ..  ..

1. Get a one star rank or higher on each 150cc mirror mode cups
2. Have a save file on Mario galaxy and get 50/80 stars

I recommend using the first way, for it is easier ( but not actually easy ). Both of the ways are rather hard to accomplish, but once you unlock rosalina it is definitely worth the trouble.

NOTE: The star or "Luma", as it is called in Mario galaxy, floating besides her is not an extra thing to unlock. It comes automatically with Rosalina in every car or bike she drives.

Comment: How is this different from the [already existing answers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/737/181240)?

Answer (score -2):

You can unlock her by getting at least 1 star rank on the mushroom cup.

Comment: Do you have a source for your information?